# Неправльная кодировка в Qt Creator

Tags: qt, кодировка, qtcreator

В поле, где отображаются ошибки, русский язык выводится "немного" не так как надо. Как поменять кодировку, для правильного отображения?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Известный баг в связке компилятор-windows-qt creator. Ссылка на [оффициальный баг](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-316?focusedCommentId=277837&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel).

Как пофиксить?

Утверждается, что оно пофикшено и в настройках в Environment->Interface - Text Codec for locale выбрать русский или тот язык, которым установлена локализация (на странице по ссылке выше ищите скриншот в самом конце).

Способ получше (как по мне) - удалить русскоязычную локализацию для студии. Да ДА! именно так. Теперь ошибки будут на английском, но оно лучше - гуглить их будет на порядок легче. Как и понимать. Это можно сделать в инсталляторе, так и просто удалив файл `%VSINSTALLDIR%\VC\bin\1049\clui.dll` (это также есть по ссылке выше).

Еще предлагается выставить переменную окружения

```
set VSLANG=1033
```

которая сделает тоже, только без удаления файла.

Связанный баг - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770956/dev-console-encoding-error-in-qt-creator

там предлагают пофиксить jom.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Можно пофиксить одной галочкой:

- Переходим в Options -> Kits.
- Выбираем нужный комплект
- Ставим галочку "Force MSVC UTF-8 Compiler Output"